# Hex-Rays and IDA Python plugin loading order

Tags: idapython, ida-plugin, hexrays

I have made a plugin (using IDA Python) that requires the Hex-Rays plugin.

As per the instructions in the `hexrays_sdk` folder, I've named my plugin starting with `hexrays_` to make sure it loads after Hex-Rays is done loading. However, IDA decides to load my plugin earlier, and hence, it never is able to get `True` for `idaapi.init_hexrays_plugin()`.

I've tried renaming my plugin in multiple ways, but still cannot seem to get the plugin to load after Hex-Rays.

BTW, I think the issue might be related to the fact that I am storing my plugin in `%IDAUSR%/plugins` rather than `%IDADIR%/plugins` since I do not want to modify `%IDADIR%`.

Is there any kind of workaround to make the plugin load later? Or can I force IDA to load Hex-Rays earlier?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When loading plugins, IDA goes through them alphabetically, and tries to load all the plugins.
When loading a plugin, the loader check the plugin flags (`idaapi.PLUGIN_PROC`, `idaapi.PLUGIN_FIX`, and so on) to determine if the plugin should be loaded at the current time.
If it is to be loaded, the `init` method is called. A plugin can return `PLUGIN_KEEP` to remain loaded, or `PLUGIN_SKIP` to avoid loading.
As long as a plugin is not in memory (not yet loaded, or already unloaded,) IDA will try and load it again and again. This is how my [plugin loader](https://github.com/tmr232/Sark/blob/master/plugins/plugin_loader.py) works.

So the first thing you need to be sure of, is that you flag your plugin `idaapi.PLUGIN_PROC`, as this is when Hex-Rays loads (only when a processor module is active.)
Hopefully, this will solve it. If not - you can use `idaapi.load_plugin('hexrays')` to explicitly load the Hex-Rays plugin. Again, this can only be done when a processor module is active, so be sure to use `PLUGIN_PROC`.

Comment: Or `idaapi.load_plugin('hexx64')`

Answer (score 0):

```
def init():
    if not idaapi.init_hexrays_plugin():
        return idaapi.PLUGIN_SKIP
```